# Google Apps Script Spreadsheets - Assign script to image from a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to generate images with a script assigned to it using another script. I know you can insert images from a script [link here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage%28String,Integer,Integer%29), but I can't find a way to assign a script to that image from a script. I found someone requesting this feature [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=525), but with no solution or workaround. If someone knows any way to insert a button that runs a script from another script into a spreadsheet, I would like to know it.

Edit: I have thought about using a trigger that would get the event source container and run a script on cell edit [described here sort of](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#ActionTriggers), but I would love a gui.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a cool feature, but here is a possible workaround, it might even offer more functionality.

You can build a UI using Google API.

More detailes [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui).

The UI allows you to create side bars/menus/etc. You could even create floating dialog windows. Using [AbsolutePanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/absolute-panel), you can even choose where the dialogue shows up.